# Running python script with php - working in console not in web browser

Tags: php, python, shell, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to run a python file from php in ec2 instance.
It's working in ssh console using `php index.php` 
But it's not working in Web browser properly.

I am having a python program which takes input and generates images

if input is 'a red flower' it will generate red flower using tensorflow and nltk.

Here something different i noticed.
When i input this code in python file

My python code snippt:

```
import getpass
username = getpass.getuser()
print username
```

and run it from console using `php index.php` i get output `bitnami`
but when i run same code using my web browser i get output `daemon`

My php code snippet:

```
<?php  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
define('ROOTPATH', dirname(__FILE__));
$output = exec('python test.py');
echo $output;
?>
```

**Expected result**: Image should be saved on server using python script

**Actual result** : Image is only saving if php script runs from console

Comment: do you have apache or any web server installed on your ec2 instance?

Comment: Yes, Apache is already installed and I don't  think any environment settings are missiing because php and python are running smoothly. I'm having doubt is that problem with user permissions? Check my above question where k mentioned bitnami and daemon

Comment: Did you tried to use full path of python? maybe `/usr/bin/python` instead of `python`

Comment: Problem solved! Check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
As i mentioned in my question i was having problem with some kind of user privileges i modified my code and forced it to use bitnami as user and now its working!

```
<?php  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
define('ROOTPATH', dirname(__FILE__));
$output = shell_exec('sudo -H -u bitnami python test.py ');
echo $output;
?>
```